# Cosets and Lagrange theorem

Tags: group-theory

Can I get some help of how to proof this question? I am stuck!

Let $n$ be a natural number. Prove that if $G$ is a group of size $n$, and $H\le G$ is a subgroup of order $n-1$ , then $n=2$

Comment: Your question title contains two terms that are quite helpful in solving this exercise.

Comment: You're welcome, @EmmanuelMani

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For what natural numbers $\;n\;$ is $\,n-1\,$ a divisor of $\,n\;$ ?

Comment: I do not know which natural numbers n ,n-1 a divisor of n.Can u help?

Comment: @EmmanuelMani, by your original question I deduce you must be a college/university student or, at the very least, an advanced high school one. For what $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ can we write $\,n=k(n-1)\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ ? This is a **very basic** question which, together with Lagrange's Theorem will give you the answer to your question...